# Cycles and Multiple cascade Paths using EF Code First

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, ef-code-first

I'm getting so confused!!!
This is my first time using MVC3 and EF Code First. I'm getting the following error:

> Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'FK_dbo.CityUsers_dbo.Cities_CityID' on table 'CityUsers' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints.
>   Could not create constraint.

I have been working on it for hours and done whatever I could but just unable to handle that!

The Scenario is that, there is a **Man** class from which the **User** is derived. *Every user belongs to only ONE City*. By user I mean admin users. Each of them can Insert/Update several Cities and each City can be modified by only one User at a time.
I have created a third table named **'CityUser'** to track users who modify City records.

Here is my model classes:

```
public class Man
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema.DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public long ID { get; set; }
    //------------------------------------------------------------//
    [Required, MaxLength(20)]
    [LocalizedAttribute("FName")]
    public string FName { get; set; }
    //------------------------------------------------------------//
    [Required, MaxLength(20)]
    [LocalizedAttribute("LastName")]
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    //------------------------------------------------------------//
    [Required]
    [RegularExpression("^[0-9]+$", ErrorMessageResourceName = "ErrorOnlyNumbers", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(MAHAL_E_MA_Model.Properties.Resources))]
    [LocalizedAttribute("Mobile")]
    public string Mobile { get; set; }
    //------------------------------------------------------------//
    [LocalizedAttribute("Phone")]
    [RegularExpression("^[0-9]+$", ErrorMessageResourceName = "ErrorOnlyNumbers", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(MAHAL_E_MA_Model.Properties.Resources))]
    public string HomePhone { get; set; }
    //------------------------------------------------------------//
    [RegularExpression("^[0-9]+$")]
    [LocalizedAttribute("IDCardNumber")]
    public string IDCardNumber { get; set; }
    //------------------------------------------------------------//
    [RegularExpression("^[0-9]+$")]
    [LocalizedAttribute("NationalCode")]
    public string NationalCode { get; set; }
    //------------------------------------------------------------//
    [MaxLength(10)]
    [LocalizedAttribute("DOB")]
    public int DOB { get; set; }
    //------------------------------------------------------------//
    [Required]
    public int CityID { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("CityID")]
    public virtual City CityParent { get; set; }
    //------------------------------------------------------------//
    [MaxLength(100)]
    [LocalizedAttribute("Address")]
    public string Address { get; set; }
    //------------------------------------------------------------//
    [LocalizedAttribute("PostalCode")]
    public string PostalCode { get; set; }
    //------------------------------------------------------------//
    [MaxLength(255)]
    [LocalizedAttribute("PhotoPath")]
    public string PhotoPath { get; set; }
}

 public class User : Man
{
    [MaxLength(20)]
    [LocalizedAttribute("Username")]
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    //------------------------------------------------------------//
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [MaxLength(100), MinLength(6, ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(MAHAL_E_MA_Model.Properties.Resources), ErrorMessageResourceName = "ErrorPasswordLength")]
    [LocalizedAttribute("Password")]
    public string Password { get; set; }
    //------------------------------------------------------------//
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Compare("Password", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(MAHAL_E_MA_Model.Properties.Resources), ErrorMessageResourceName = "ErrorConfirmPassword")]
    [LocalizedAttribute("ConfirmPassword")]
    public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }
    //------------------------------------------------------------//
    [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress, ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(MAHAL_E_MA_Model.Properties.Resources), ErrorMessageResourceName = "ErrorEmailInvalid")]
    [MaxLength(20)]
    [RegularExpression(@"[a-zA-Z0-9._%+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,}")]
    [LocalizedAttribute("Email")]
    public string Email { get; set; }
    //------------------------------------------------------------//
    [MaxLength(30)]
    [LocalizedAttribute("Title")]
    public string Title { get; set; }
    //------------------------------------------------------------//
    [MaxLength(10)]
    [LocalizedAttribute("HireDate")]
    public int HireDate { get; set; }
    //------------------------------------------------------------//
    [LocalizedAttribute("ReportsTo")]
    public long ReportsTo { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("ReportsTo")]
    public virtual IList<User> ReportsChild { get; set; }
}

public class City
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema.DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int CityID { get; set; }
    //------------------------------------------------------------//
    [Required, MaxLength(20)]
    [LocalizedAttribute("Name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    //------------------------------------------------------------//
    [LocalizedAttribute("PhoneCode")]
    public int PhoneCode { get; set; }
    //------------------------------------------------------------//
    [Required, MaxLength(10)]
    public int ModifiedDate { get; set; }
}

public class CityUser
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema.DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int CityUserID { get; set; }
    //------------------------------------------------------------//
    [Required]
    public long ModifiedByUserID { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("ModifiedByUserID")]
    public virtual User OperatorUser { get; set; }
    //------------------------------------------------------------//
    [Required]
    public int CityID { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("CityID")]
    public virtual City City { get; set; }
}
```

But as EF5 goes for creating the database the error mentioned earlier comes out!!!
What can I do for that?? I've read so many weblogs for that done some amendment on the Data Model.. But still cannot get ride of that error.... By the way, I want to declare relationships using **DataAnnotations**.

Now is there anyone who can get me out of this problem???!!!! :(

Regards,

Comment: Does the error mean that, If the City be deleted from the City table then the record/s related to the CityID in CityUser table will also be deleted? If so, I don't know how to handle it.. I used to handle that in programming, for example, as the Delete Method is called, firstly I used to consider if the record has any children. I have no idea in code first!!! Please help...

Comment: It says that there are many references to `CityId` i.e. Man[, User] and city user has reference to the `City` via `CityId`, so it asks you to specify a `ON DELETE` & `ON UPDATE` actions since it could not automatically infer them.

Comment: Ok.. let me ask you.. Do I have to define a navigation property on the parent class, for instance, public virtual ICollection<CityUser> CityUsers {get;set;}??? Does it make any difference? Did I correctly define the Foreign Keys? Any Idea?

Comment: You should be providing the navigation properties to get the users who modified the city and also the cities that are created by a user. Hope it makes sense

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally, I could come over this after hours and lots of efforts and by this way will never and ever forget the concept!!! :D
The solution found:

```
modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<OneToManyCascadeDeleteConvention>();
```